# Is there an easy way to establish which Variation Sequences a font supports?

Tags: fonts, japanese

I am looking for a method or a script that would allow, on a large scale, determine the Unicode SVS and IVS supporting capabilities. For instance, I’m in need of a font supporting a Moji Joho sequence <4E0E,E0104>. I could just manually check any of many CJK fonts I have until I find one, but is there a not time-consuming method? Is it possible to somehow make a list of all instances of “character, selector” sequences that have characters encoded?

Comment: Though I'm not sure about the general method, the JP government official [IPAmj明朝](https://mojikiban.ipa.go.jp/1300.html) contains all Moji_Joho IVSes, because it was made for them.